# Want to make the logic Java8 Compatible and More Efficient

Tags: java, java-8

I have written a Logic which does some calculation over a Hashmap and returns a String.
I want to write it using more efficient way by using Java8 features and Apache Commons Features.
The logic works without any issue but does not clean and readable enough.

```
public String giveMeTheRightOrder(CustomObject customObject) {

String  order = null;

  Map<ArticleType , ArticleStatus > objMap = customObject.getArticles();
 boolean isArticleClothing = false;
 boolean isArticleFoodItem = false;

  if(objMap != null && objMap.size() == 2) {
          for(ArticleType articleType : objMap.keySet()) {

             if(articleType.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(ArticleType.CLOTH.toString())) {
                       isArticleClothing  = true;
        }
               if(articleType.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(ArticleType.FOOD.toString())) {
                       isArticleFoodItem = true;
        }

    }
           if(isArticleClothing  && isArticleFoodItem ){
                 int liveCount = 0;
              for(ArticleStatus articleStatus : objMap.values() ) {
                 if(articleStatus.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(ArticleStatus.LIVE.toString() )) {
                       liveCount++;
            }
        }
        if(liveCount  != 2 )
            {
                           for(Map.Entry<ArticleType , ArticleStatus> entry : objMap.entrySet()) {
                if(entry.getValue().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(ArticleStatus.LIVE.toString()) {
                    
                    order  = entry.getKey().toString();
                                         break;
                }
            }
        } else {
                         order = ArticleType.CLOTH.tostring();
        }
            } else {
                     order = "COMPLETE";
        }
    }

        for(Map.Entry<ArticleType, ArticleStatus> entry : objMap.entrySet() ) {
                  if(entry.getValue().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(ArticleStatus.LIVE.toString())){
                         order = entry.getKey().toString();
                         break;
        }
            else{
                   order = "COMPLETE";
        }

    }
     return order;
}
```

Comment: Refer Java 8 Streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code:

if the map has both keys(`ArticleType.CLOTH` and `ArticleType.FOOD`) then you count `LIVE` value in map. then if `countLive` amount is not 2,you have looped over map and finded first key that its value is `LIVE` in other hand you have set `CLOTH` that I think it is not needed.

in case of map size is 2 you can do like this: if both keys are `LIVE` then return `ArticleType.CLOTH`

```
if (objMap != null && objMap.size() == 2) {
   if (ArticleStatus.LIVE.equals(objMap.get(ArticleType.CLOTH)) && 
        ArticleStatus.LIVE.equals(objMap.get(ArticleType.FOOD))) {
      return ArticleType.CLOTH.toString();
   }
}
```

for other condition you can do like this:

```
return objMap.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().toString()
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(ArticleStatus.LIVE.toString()))
            .findFirst().map(entry -> entry.getKey().toString()).orElse("COMPLETE");
```

complete code is like this:

```
  public String giveMeTheRightOrder(CustomObject customObject) {
    Map<ArticleType, ArticleStatus> objMap = customObject.getArticles();
    if(objMap == null) return "COMPLETE";
    if (objMap.size() == 2) {
        if (ArticleStatus.LIVE.equals(objMap.get(ArticleType.CLOTH)) &&
             ArticleStatus.LIVE.equals(objMap.get(ArticleType.FOOD))) {
          return ArticleType.CLOTH.toString();
        }
    }
    return objMap.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().toString()
                     .equalsIgnoreCase(ArticleStatus.LIVE.toString()))
            .findFirst()
            .map(entry -> entry.getKey().toString()).orElse("COMPLETE");
}
```